# Excel - Highlight active row

Tags: excel, notepad++

Wondering if there is some preference I can set in excel so that when I am in a specific cell the entire row is slightly highlighted (not overly so but enough to easily tell it out)

Similar to the fashion that Notepad++ works in tab delimeted files, and highlights the entire row.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This should be in SuperUser...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know of any built-in preferences in Excel to do this but it can be done using VBA. Place the following in "ThisWorkbook" of the VBAProject:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Tgt As Range)
    If Tgt.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        ActiveSheet.Rows(Tgt.Row).Select
        Tgt.Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

The code only highlights the active row if a single cell is selected so that it does not interfere when multiple cells are selected.

Comment: I appreciate this solution as it does not force recalculation and does not remove the background colors all over the sheet as other solutions I tested so far.